# Striving to write efficient code

Tags: java, if-statement

I am writing code for a large scale app, and there is an event where lots of `if`/`else` checks are required.

For example:

```
if (i == 1) { /* some logic */ }
else if (i == 2) { /* some logic */ }
// ...
// ...
else if (i == 1000) { /* some logic */ }
```

Is there a more efficient or organised way to write this?

Comment: Yes. It's called a `switch` statement.

Comment: Yes, but the problem remains the i.e each "case" statement will be checked, and code will be again be so long.

Comment: Either switch or depending on what your "logic" is, it may be possible to automate it more.

Comment: Check the most likely case first.  If `i=592` 95% of the time, start with that check first

Comment: The _java_ switch statement compiles to an efficient lookup.

Comment: Have you measured whether or not it is inefficient?  Don’t assume - test!

Comment: Besides, code length and efficiency are generally unrelated.

Comment: No, the problem *won't* remain. `switch` statements with 1000 cases don't compile to `if-else` chains.

Comment: @KenWhite No, they do *not* 'both basically do the same thing'. Have a look at the object code some time.

Comment: Depending on what the logic is, it might make sense to make 1000 `Runnable` objects, store them in a `Runnable[]`, then do an array lookup when you need them.  This might work if there's lots in common between the various parts.

Comment: The question is has absolutely no ambiguity. The intention is clear. The code is clear. The answers are clear. That a design pattern may be useful in the asker's program is possible, but not necessarily so. The asker has 17 rep. Can't we be nice and give him a little leeway during a holiday season?

Comment: As an exercise, if there aren't a lot of gaps in between options, you could store the logic in an array. Not terribly efficient memory-wise, but pretty fast, I imagine.

Comment: @carpeliam Almos as fast as a `switch` statement, which already does exactly that with the branch targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a collection of functions and you just need to use a `HashMap`. `i` would be index of the map. Hashmaps are useful because they find the corresponding value for a key quickly, without having to compare lots of values until a match is found.

Here is an example of a `HashMap` from `Any` to `Any => Any`. Because Scala supports tuples, this is a completely general solution.

```
object Hello extends App {
  import scala.collection.immutable

  type F1 = (Any) => Any

  val hashMap: immutable.Map[Int, F1] =
    immutable.HashMap[Int, F1](
      1    -> { (a: Int)               => a * 2               }.asInstanceOf[F1], // Function literal that doubles it's input
      2    -> { (tuple: (String, Int)) => tuple._1 * tuple._2 }.asInstanceOf[F1], // Function literal that repeats the string
      1000 -> { (_: Unit)              => s"The date and time is ${ new java.util.Date() }" }.asInstanceOf[F1]
    )

  def lookup(i: Int, args: Any): Any = hashMap(i)(args)

  def report(i: Int, args: Any): Unit = println(s"$i: ${ lookup(i, args) }")

  report(1, 21)
  report(2, ("word ", 5))
  report(1000, ())
}
```

Here is the output:

```
1: 42
2: word word word word word 
1000: The date and time is Sat Dec 23 19:45:56 PST 2017
```

**Update:** Here is a version that uses an array. Notice that the indices must start at 0 for this version, not an arbitrary number as before:

```
object Hello2 extends App {
  type F1 = (Any) => Any

  val array: Array[F1] =
    Array[F1](
      { (a: Int)               => a * 2               }.asInstanceOf[F1], // Function literal that doubles it's input
      { (tuple: (String, Int)) => tuple._1 * tuple._2 }.asInstanceOf[F1], // Function literal that repeats the string
      { (_: Unit)              => s"The date and time is ${ new java.util.Date() }" }.asInstanceOf[F1]
    )

  def lookup(i: Int, args: Any): Any = array(i)(args)

  def report(i: Int, args: Any): Unit = println(s"$i: ${ lookup(i, args) }")

  report(0, 21)
  report(1, ("word ", 5))
  report(2, ())
}
```

Output is:

```
0: 42
1: word word word word word 
2: The date and time is Sat Dec 23 20:32:33 PST 2017
```

Comment: An array would  be much more efficient than a hash map if the numbers were contiguous since it would eliminate the hash computation (however cheap it is for integers) and ensure that there would never be a collision resulting from an unfortunate choice of table size.

Comment: True, but the OP did not state that could be assumed.

Comment: He did, the set 1, 2, ..., 1000 is generally known as the set of integers 1-1000

Comment: The array case can be trivially adapted to work with any fixed starting number, not just zero: given number `i` and starting offset `s`, the index is just `i - s`.

Comment: It took me a second to realize that you were writing in Scala (which I know nothing about), since the OP tagged Java. +1 regardless.

Comment: The OP originally tagged Scala and Java, and said Scala in the heading. He has since changed the heading and the tag.

Comment: A `switch` would be considerably more efficient than this.

Comment: @EJP That is somewhat true when only a handful of functions need to be accessed, but "considerably" is an overstatement. However, since we are looking at least thousands of functions, I think that a switch statement would be less efficient than what I have shown, and any statement spanning multiple screens would be very hard to maintain. Of course, you would want to select the appropriate implementation (map or array), depending on the circumstance.

Comment: @MikeSlinn It is *entirely* true *regardless* of the number of cases. That's what it is designed for, and generations of compiler writers have slaved over producing far more efficient implementations that anything you can accomplish in source code. What you think isn't relevant. If you can produce measurements that support your case, please do so.

Answer (score 3):

Use a switch statement.
Ex.

```
switch(variable) {
    case 1: 
        //DoStuff
        break;
    case 2: 
        //DoStuff
        break;
    default: 
        //Dostuff
        break;
}
```

Alternatively, if you know the most common case, you can break it down from there to improve algorithmic run time which may require a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing 1000 **distinct** things in those code blocks, then the problem is logic complexity. In that case, you have no option but to code like that or to change to a `switch`.
In the case of `if`, the only key thing to remember is to move to the top the cases you know to be most likely/frequent.

If you aren't doing 1000 different things that have to be **individually coded**, then you can consider some of these options:

1. Break down into ranges, if that's possible:

   ```
   if(i < 300): {
       //do something
   } else if(i < 600) {
       // do another thing
   } 
   //do the default thing
   ```
2. If the logic can be programmed and the value of `i` can be used as an argument used to decide implementation logic, then you can use abstraction:

   ```
   abstract class NumberProcessor {
       protected int i;
       static NumberProcessor getInstance(int i){
          //Use this block to look at the number and choose one of few implementations...
          //and store number in the instance
       }

       abstract void processNumber();
   }
   ```

You can then write a few implementations based on whatever logic you can group on.

Comment: You don't have to know which is most frequent in a `switch` statement, nor to move those cases to the top.